# CMake: how to set -B parameter (path-to-build) inside CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

Is there some system variable in CMakeLists.txt to set all build temporary files to specified dir (CMakeCache, CMakeFiles, build artifacts, etc)? This can be done using command line parameter -B (path-to-build), but I need it inside CMakeLists.txt to set default dir for all files, which are not-tracked with git

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a build directory via command line, it always overwrites any values from other sources.

You can achieve something similar to the effect you desire using [cmake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), but it's a relatively new addition (= version 3.19) to the cmake features and it doesn't specify the build directory inside the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but inside a `CMakePresets.json` file.

The presence of the file won't break the project for older cmake versions, but the initial configuration becomes less convenient.

**CMakePresets.json** (place next to the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`)

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "makefiles",
      "displayName": "Default configuration",
      "description": "Default config",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "../build"
    }
  ]
}
```

This allows you to choose the default build location as a sibling directory of the source dir using

```
cmake --preset makefiles .
```

This uses the sibling directory `build` of the source directory as the binary directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for it. You use the `binaryDir` property and never again you need to provide the `-B` argument as long as you use presets to generate your project files and/or build your project.